# Creating pie chart from single data row - SAS analytics

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that consists of a product variable, an area variable and then each of the years from the last 10 years as an individual variable, so 12 variables in total for the dataset.

I cant work out how to display the data from a single row into a pie chart.

The dataset looks as such just to make it easier to visualise:

```
Product  Area  year1  year2  year3
  1       1     7      14      7  
  1       2     12     15      11
  1       3     5      9       8
  2       1     4      12      5
  2       2     8      3       14
  2       3     5      0       2
  3       1     2      12      12
```

My end result is to be able to input say product 1 and area 3 and then have it produce a pie chart that shows the values for each of the years. I can't figure out a way of doing it though, my current knowledge and research suggests that pulling from a single row isn't possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First stack the years variables in one colum with proc transpose ;
2. Then make a normal pie chart with `BY Product Area;` to have one chart per original line (assuming Product*Area is actually a unique ID for you lines). I used `proc gchart` here.

   ```
   *** DEFINE DATA --------------;
   data have;
       infile datalines dlm=' ';
       input Product  Area  year1  year2  year3;
       datalines;
   1 1 7 14 7
   1 2 12 15 11
   1 3 5 9 8
   2 1 4 12 5
   2 2 8 3 14
   2 3 5 0 2
   3 1 2 12 12
   ;run;

   *** STACK YEARS --------------;
   proc sort data=work.have out=work.tmp0temptableinput;
       by product area;
       run;
   proc sql;
       create view work.tt1 as
       select src.*, "values" as _eg_idcol_
       from work.tmp0temptableinput as src;
       quit;
   proc transpose data=work.tt1
           out=work.tt2
           name=year;
       by product area;
       id _eg_idcol_;
       var year:; * THIS IS GENERALISED FOR FOR THAN 3 YEARxx VARIABLES;
       run;
   proc datasets lib=work nolist;
       modify tt2;
       label values = ;
       label year = ;
       label valuedescription = ;
       run;

   *** PLOT --------------;
   proc sort
       data=work.tt2
       out=work.tt3;
       by product area;
       run;
   proc gchart data =work.tt3;
       pie  year /
           sumvar=values
           type=sum
           nolegend
           slice=outside
           percent=none
           value=outside
           other=4
           otherlabel="other"
           coutline=black
           noheading
           ;
       by product area;
       run; quit;
   ```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.